# Sencha Touch - Hide Item in TabBar

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

I would like to hide the ThankYou item in the tab bar until the use submits the contact us form. Once the form is submitted, I'd like the ThankYou item to be shown, and the other three items to be hidden. Is this possible? Here's my code:

```
Mobile.views.ViewPort = Ext.extend(Ext.TabPanel, {
    fullscreen: true,
    layout: 'card',
    tabBar: {
                layout: { pack: 'center' }
            },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'Landing'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'AboutUs'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'ContactUs'
        },
        {
            id: 'ThankYou',
            name: 'ThankYou',
            xtype: 'ThankYou',
            hidden: true //Not working
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dont include the ThankYou panel in TabPanel rather use a Sheet that you will set to display (using show() ) once user has submitted the form.

Alternatively if you want to use the TabPanel, do not include the ThankYou panel in the items array and once you submit the form do:

```
Mobile.views.ViewPort.setActiveItem(new Mobile.views.ThankYou(),animationOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Are the other requirements just as easy? This solution adds ThankYou to the TabBar, but I still need to remove Landing, AboutUs, and ContactUs.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer since you got me pointed in the right direction. Thanks for your help. Here was the solution to remove the other items: `Mobile.views.ViewPort.remove("Landing");`